# Corrupted PDF when downloading through React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, encoding, character-encoding

I have a pdf uploaded in a Azure Blobstorage and I'm facing some problems during the download routine.
My application runs with springboot and I use an `OutputStream` provided by a `HttpServletResponse` in a `@RestController` method to stream the bytes from the blobstorage to the request.

In the frontend I have a Reac application receiving the information and executing the download through the browser.
Every time I stream the bytes to the frontend I got a corrupted file. It works just fine when I execute a request through Insomnia or Postman.

I tried to compare the files as texts and I could see some differences between them.

#### Differences

- The size of the corrupted file is almost double the size of the original
  [image]
- When I opened files on Notepad++ they seems to be in a different encoding
  corrupted
  [image: corrupted file]
  consistent
  [image: consistent file]
- It looks like there are some characters bad interpreted
  corrupted
  [image: corrupted characters]
  consistent
  [image]

My frontend uses `FileSaver` @2.0.2 to persist the file on disk

```
  const blobParts = [];
  const blobOptions = {
    type: axiosResponse.headers['content-type'],
  };
  blobParts.push(axiosResponse.data);

  const file = new File(
    blobParts,
    axiosResponse.headers['content-disposition'].split('=')[1],
    blobOptions,
  );

 return FileSaver.saveAs(file);
```

I'm wondering if there's a way of keep the ANSI encoding through the persistence process or if there's is a way

Comment: "ANSI" is not a well-defined encoding (Notepad++ probably inherited this incorrect terminology from Microsoft, but it should properly tell you which code page the file actually uses; probably in your case code page 1252? The editor is obviously using heuristics to decide this anyway; strictly speaking, you should figure out what the correct encoding is by other means.) You are doing something wrong if you are treating binary data as text in the first place. What content-type does the server give you?

Comment: The content-type is a application/pdf. If I download it straight from the blobstorage it also works just fine